# How to find width using a formula with CSS

Tags: css, function

How to to use CSS functions to calculate a div width in percentage using this formula : `(screen-width - 300px) x 100 / screen-width`

**EDIT 1 :**

I explain more the problem :

My navigation side as showed in the below image have always `300px` as widh and the content side must have the rest of screen-width so it would be : `navigation-side + content-side = 100%`

[image]

Comment: There is no such thing as CSS functions unless you mean `calc`

Comment: As @Paulie_D said, I think you can handle this operation  with `calc` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: @VincentG even with calc you will not be able to have the division

Comment: can you elaborate more your use case so we can better help you?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve you probably need javascript

Comment: I edited my question to clarify more the problem

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to use `calc()` function this way :

```
.content-side {
   width: calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

Actually I didn't know that we can use the value 100% to express the screen-width and substract a value expressed in `px`